# Scheme - n-ary subtraction function issues

Tags: scheme, subtraction, built-in

I have the following n-ary function I defined:

```
(define (- . l)
(cond   ((null? l) 0)
        (else (b- (car l) (apply - (cdr l))))))
```

It works fine for two arguments, but anymore and it starts to add numbers in a strange way and I don't understand why.

Alternatively, I have a check implemented in a different version of this function in case there is only one argument:

```
(define (- . l)
(cond   ((null? (cdr l)) (b- (b* l 2) l))
        (else (b- (car l) (apply - (cdr l))))))
```

This second one does not work at all when I change the first condition. 
Input should be something like `(- 10 6 1)`

Comment: Remember that you can't just change the order the substractions happen in. Your function is calculating `10 - (6 - 1)` -> `5`, instead of `(10 - 6) - 1` -> `3`.

Comment: Or, to put it differently, `(- a b c)` is `(- a (+ b c))`, not `(- a (- b c))`. (And your second version attempts to mulitply and subtract a list; the single argument is `(car l)`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that `b-` is a binary subtraction, and that you want to mimic the usual subtraction of Scheme, which is a function such that:

1. with no arguments, gives an error,
2. with an argument, changes the sign of the argument,
3. with more than one argument, substracts from the first one all the others.

Here is a possibile solution (note that I've called the function `n-`):

```
(define (n- . l)
  (define (aux l dec)
    (if (null? l)
        dec
        (aux (cdr l) (b- dec (car l)))))
  (cond ((null? l) (println "Error"))
        ((null? (cdr l)) (b- 0 (car l)))
        (else (aux (cdr l) (car l)))))

(n-)            ; => Error
(n- 3)          ; => -3
(n- 10 6 1)     ; =>  3
(n- 11 4 8 2)   ; => -3
```

The auxiliary function subtracts all the numbers from the list first argument to its second argument, and it is defined as a tail recursive function, so that it can be implemented in an iterative way.

Answer (score 2):

The sane way to implement `-` is by using `case-lambda`, so that the unary, binary, and variadic cases can be handled separately:

```
(define -
  (case-lambda
    ((a) (b- 0 a))
    ((a b) (b- a b))
    ((a b . rest) (apply - (b- a b) rest))))
```

Now, if you don't have `case-lambda`, then you'll have more work to do:

```
(define (- a . rest)
  (if (null? rest)
      (b- 0 a)
      (let loop ((result a)
                 (rest rest))
        (if (null? rest)
            result
            (loop (b- result (car rest)) (cdr rest))))))
```

This special-cases unary invocation to negate; otherwise, it iterates, using the first argument as the initial result, and updates the result by subtraction each time.